# Download app update once, install twice/thrice?

Tags: software-update, software

I have a very slow internet connection and would like to be able to download app updates (iTunes, Aperture, iWork etc.) just for one machine and be able to update 3 machines offline on home network. Is this possible on Mavericks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Caching Server" is one of the features of OS X Server. Whenever one of your computers (iOS or OS X) downloads an update it is cached on the server.  This link has a simple description: [Caching Server](http://www.apple.com/osx/server/features/#caching-server)

This is the *official* solution that Apple provide.  It does mean another level of complexity to managing your network and only you you will be able to decide whether you want to follow the OS X Server path. From my point of view, I would not unless I intended to use some of the other features of OS X Server (e.g. centralised Time Machine). The *server* Mac can continue to be used for desktop activity.

Comment: Ha - nice, you beat me by seconds... ;)

Comment: Thanks to you both! Your caveats aside, I may treat myself to the Server.app as I feel like I owe Apple money for the free Mavericks release (cough cough). More seriously I need a distraction to get me through the 'dark months'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

You can install Mavericks Server (Server costs $20 from the Apple Store), and activate the Caching Server.

From Apple:

> The Caching server speeds up the download of software distributed by
>   Apple through the Internet. It caches all software updates, App Store
>   purchases, iBooks, iTunes U (apps and books purchases only), and
>   Internet Recovery software that local Mac and iOS devices download.

Comment: Great minds think alike ;-)